# Android Studio: Import module window is too big, can't get any further?

Tags: android, android-studio, import, module, dji-sdk

I have a problem. I tried to import the DJI SDK (https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/), but at the last step I'm getting a window as you can see in the picture. I'm not able to get to the bottom of the window to get any further and can't resize the window (tried several key combinations). Is there any way to avoid this problem and to import the SDK?

Picture of described problem (File -> New -> Import Module -> ..?):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your way to import the SDK is correct, but please make sure you download the latest version of the ANDROID MOBILE SDK V3.2.1:
https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/downloads/

And then import the correct library folder as below:
[here is my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvUmI.png)

Hope this can help.

Comment: Also DJI provided documentation on how to import the SDK:
https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html#android-studio-project-integration

Comment: Jesus Christ, I dowloaded the previous version, must have had a brainfart. Thanks for your help anyways :)

Comment: @Berserk0r I did the same thing. I clicked the button labeled 'zip'